# Is there an efficient way to perform this project?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-button

I am learning Android Studio and I have recently come across listview.

I am making a project which has 6 buttons and each of those 6 buttons will open an activity where there are 2 additional buttons and if you click on 1 of those 2 activities you will reach the required page.The required pages have different text content.

I am approaching this problem by creating a new xml file for every activity however this leads to creation of many pages and I just wanted to know if there is any method which will reduce the number of files created for this project

Comment: Add the text you want to show as a parameter to the Intent when starting the activity. Then get the text from the Intent in the final page and show this Text

Answer (score 0):

If your two activity have similar look than you can use same layout,
else you have to create different layouts for all your activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Activities that looks alike you can use the same layout file for both activities, and only change the behavior in the Java side.

And if you have activities thats acts alike you can also use the same activity and change the behavior depending on some extras.